# CEPH storage can be used via RGW service or directly by librados. Which one is better to use from microservice?

Tags: ceph

I am planning to use CEPH as storage of video files. RHEL CEPH provides options to store directly using librados or using RGW. I am curious to know which implementation is used more in the industry. Specifically if I do GET/PUT/DELETE operation from springboot microservice.

Answer (score 1):

RGW exposes an S3 interface, whereas RADOS exposes its own object protocol.

While coding to RADOS directly has some advantages, coding to S3 benefits from a large ecosystem where you can choose any language and pick between literally hundreds of tools and libraries.

99% of Ceph users write/deploy applications that interact with RGW when using object stores. Only 1-2% write custom applications via RADOS.

The advice here is to use RGW’s s3 interface, and only consider RADOS for specialized, high-performance tailored applications.